# backbone.js - sample todo app change

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the [sample app](http://todolist.parseapp.com/) how can i alter the label "What needs to be done" in the input field depending on the the size of the collection returned by the "fetch()" ??

I put up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rowntreerob/hW5h2/4/) , in which i changed the template to get the label for the field from "variables" field 
passed in to the template on line 168.

> ```
> initialize: function() {
>   var self = this;
>     var variables = { input_label : "Que needs to be done" };  
>
>   _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll', 'addSome', 'render', 'toggleAllComplete', 'logOut', 'createOnEnter');
>
>   // Main todo management template
>   this.$el.html(_.template($("#manage-todos-template").html(), variables)); // line 168
>
>   this.input = this.$("#new-todo");
>   this.allCheckbox = this.$("#toggle-all")[0];
>
>   // Create our collection of Todos
>   this.todos = new TodoList;
>
>   // Setup the query for the collection to look for todos from the current user
>   this.todos.query = new Parse.Query(Todo);
>   this.todos.query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
>
>   this.todos.bind('add',     this.addOne);
>   this.todos.bind('reset',   this.addAll);
>   this.todos.bind('all',     this.render);
>
>   // Fetch all the todo items for this user
>   this.todos.fetch();   //line 185
>
>   state.on("change", this.filter, this);
> },
> ```

After the fetch() runs on line 185, i can branch on the collection.length ( see line 252 ) but i am not able to change the UI (#new-todo) at that point.

> ```
> // Add all items in the Todos collection at once.
> addAll: function(collection, filter, variables) {
>     if(collection.length > 1)console.log("Exists " );  //line 252
>   this.$("#todo-list").html("");
>   this.todos.each(this.addOne);
> },
> ```

If the fetch returns a collection of zero items, how can i change the label ( var in 'variables' ) to a different value an have that new value reflected in the UI.

Like "You have no TODO items".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener in your ManageTodosView to listen for the reset event on your TodoList and update the label according to whatever logic you need it to:

```
var ManageTodosView = Parse.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        ...
        this.listenTo(this.todos, 'reset', this.updateLabel);
        ...
    },

    updateLabel: function () {

        var label = this.todos.length === 0 ? 'label for zero todos' : 'label for non-zero todos';

        this.$el.find('whatever selector you need here').val(label);
    }
});
```